# Port existing Bootstrap site to WordPress?

Tags: themes, css, child-theme, twitter-bootstrap

I have an existing static site, built on top of Bootstrap, with custom CSS. Now I want to move the site to WordPress (yay).

But I want to keep all the styling and layout in WordPress **exactly the same** as the existing site, as far as is possible.

What's the easiest and most future-proof way to do this? I would like to be able to upgrade WordPress in the future without having to rewrite the theme from scratch.

Ideally I'd find the "vanilla Bootstrap" theme for WordPress, make a child theme, drop in my existing CSS, tweak a few divs and PHP tags for layout, and be done.

I don't think this is an option, so should I create a child theme on top of something else? If so, what?

(I looked at the non-Bootstrap [BlankSlate](http://tidythemes.com/concept/), but it says that it doesn't recommend using child themes but rather rewriting your code yourself each time you upgrade, as a learning exercise, which doesn't sound like what I want.)

What are my best options for making WordPress look the same as a mature existing "on top of Bootstrap" site? I really don't want to have to redesign everything from scratch, just for WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, to my knowledge, there is no 'easy way' to do this. That said you shouldn't have to redesign your site from scratch and would get way with building a custom WordPress Theme yourself.

As I'm sure you're aware a WordPress theme is built upon a series of `.php` files. The process of developing a theme tends to start with static HTML / CSS files which are then used to create the various `.php` files. With this in mind you should be able to use your existing `.html` files to create `.php` versions simply by injecting WordPress (PHP) code into the relevant areas. This in itself is a huge task, depending on experience. Ideally you need a knowledge of PHP and Theme Development for WordPress - [This is a good place to start](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

---

Regarding the updating of WordPress. The WordPress Core and Themes are separate from one another meaning that there can be an update for either WordPress or a Theme. If there is an update for WordPress this won't affect the Theme in any way+.

However if you are using a pre-made theme and have amended it in anyway, once you update the Theme you will lose all your changes. That's where Child Themes come into play. A  Child Theme allows you to amend the WordPress Theme indirectly, meaning that if there is a Theme update your Child Theme will remain the same i.e. all your changes will be intact. This is a good choice if you want to make minor changes to a Theme however you would be better off creating a new one entirely, just because you'll be overwriting a lot of existing code (*just my opinion*)

+*In large updates some functions could potentially become depreciated meaning they no longer work so this is something worth keeping in mind when updating WordPress*

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I should write a vanilla Bootstrap theme for WordPress, and sell it for people to add their own child themes on top.

Comment: There's money to be made! There may be another answer than this so don't take it as definitive. Just in my opinion this would be the best way to achieve it.